# Custom report for the Behave Python framework, need to fetch the Scenario Name and its status

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, python-behave

I need to create a custom report for the Behave and Python framework, where I need to fetch the Scenario Name and the scenario status, how to acheive it?

is there any event listener class in the behave framework, in which I can able to call that class and achieve it

Behave version - 1.2.6

Answer (score 0):

You can grab and save that info from built-in `behave` methods so that you can use those values later:

```py
def before_feature(context, feature):
    save_feature = feature

def before_scenario(context, scenario):
    save_scenario = scenario
```

---

Or if using both `behave` and `selenium`, there's the `behave` integration for `seleniumbase` with an existing reporting system ([SeleniumBase behave ReadMe](https://github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase/blob/master/examples/behave_bdd/ReadMe.md)):

[image: SeleniumBase behave dashboard]

```bash
> cd examples/behave_bdd/
> behave features/calculator.feature:61 -T -D dashboard -k

Dashboard: ~/github/SeleniumBase/examples/behave_bdd/dashboard.html
********************************************************************************
Feature: SeleniumBase scenarios for the Calculator App # features/calculator.feature:1

  Background:   # features/calculator.feature:3

  Scenario: 7.0 × (3 + 3) = 42        # features/calculator.feature:49
    Given Open the Calculator App     # features/steps/calculator.py:4
    When Press C                      # features/steps/calculator.py:9
    And Press 7                       # features/steps/calculator.py:79
    And Press .                       # features/steps/calculator.py:104
    And Press 0                       # features/steps/calculator.py:94
    And Press ×                       # features/steps/calculator.py:29
    And Press (                       # features/steps/calculator.py:14
    And Press 3                       # features/steps/calculator.py:59
    And Press +                       # features/steps/calculator.py:39
    And Press 3                       # features/steps/calculator.py:59
    And Press )                       # features/steps/calculator.py:19
    Then Verify output is "7.0×(3+3)" # features/steps/calculator.py:135
    When Press =                      # features/steps/calculator.py:44
    Then Verify output is "42"        # features/steps/calculator.py:135
   ✅ Scenario Passed!

- Dashboard: ~/github/SeleniumBase/examples/behave_bdd/dashboard.html
==================================================================================
1 feature passed, 0 failed, 0 skipped
1 scenario passed, 0 failed, 8 skipped
14 steps passed, 0 failed, 60 skipped, 0 undefined
Took 0m1.672s
```